Web Scraping Javascript Page with Selenium and Python
I'm looking to scrape a list from a website, where you have to select "Yes", check the "Show by State" box, click the "Submit and Find Doctor", and then select a state from the dropdown, and note the doctor's name.
Website:
https://www.inspiresleep.com/en-us/find-a-doctor/

I'm getting stuck on the "Show by State" button. With this code:
<input id="show-by-state-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="checkbox"></span>
<span class="label-text">Show by State</span>

This is what I have so far:
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time
import requests

doctor_dict = {}

#configure webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)

driver.get("https://www.inspiresleep.com/en-us/find-a-doctor/")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Yes']").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"value = 'checkbox'").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Submit & Find a Doctor']")

Could someone help me with the error to selecting the checkbox and then clicking "Select and Find Doctor"? Is it possible to select a state from the dropdown after this page? Alternatively is there an API or something that could be used to not have to use Selenium?

should probably use proper webdriverwaits... but the selector for the checkbox looks wrong... try XPATH of: //input[@id="show-by-state-checkbox"]  For the pulldown see the special Select class:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/support_features/select_lists/

Try:
import requests

api_url = "https://www.inspiresleep.com/api/crm/get-clinics/"

payload = {
    "lat": 45.23312,
    "lng": -93.29134,
    "osa": True,
    "radius": 5000,
    "stateCode": "TX",  # <-- texas
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

for c in data["clinics"]:
    print(c["Name"])
    for d in c["Doctors"]:
        print(d["FullName"])
    print("-" * 80)
    # ... other data

Prints:
...

Wellstone ENT
Evan Longfield
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
West Texas Ear, Nose & Throat
Jason Acevedo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
West Texas ENT and Sinus Institute
Raphael Nwojo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
White Rock ENT
Jennifer Jordan
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Yadro Ducic - Head & Neck Surgery
Yadro Ducic
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Thank. you for the help. Could you tell me how you see the payload and what criteria are needed? I saw the api url, but it wouldn't load in my browser, i guess because I was missing the payload. And can I just change out the state initials only, or would I have to have a separate payload for each state with the "lat", "lon", etc.

@user3628240 I think only the stateCode needs to be changed, for example AL for Alabama etc. You can see this payload when you open Web Developer Tools in your browser, switch to Network Tab and make the request.

Here is the selenium solution.
Note: I have refactored your code by using waits instead of time.sleep()
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.get("https://www.inspiresleep.com/en-us/find-a-doctor/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
# Use below line only if you are getting the Accept/Reject cookies pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Accept All')]"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Yes']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='checkbox']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Submit & Find a Doctor']"))).click()
select = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "fad-by-state"))))
select.select_by_visible_text("Alabama")
clinics = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='FAD--step3-result gw']")))

for clinic in clinics:
    print(clinic.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h2").text)
    doctors = clinic.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='FAD--doctor-name']//h4")
    for doctor in doctors:
        print(doctor.text)
    print("----------------------------------")

Console output:
Baptist Health ENT Specialists
Dr. Cang Nguyen
Dr. Glenn Lee Watkins
----------------------------------
Birmingham VA
Dr. Kirk Withrow
----------------------------------
Ear, Nose, Throat, Head & Neck Surgery of Huntsville
Dr. Joseph Brigance
----------------------------------
East Alabama ENT, PC
Dr. W. Stites Whatley
Dr. William R. Blythe
----------------------------------
Eastern Shore Ear Nose and Throat Clinic
Dr. Ashwin Ananth
----------------------------------
ENT Centers of Excellence
Dr. Keith Kowal
----------------------------------
ENTcare Dothan
Dr. Chelsey Smith
----------------------------------
Francis Allen Long II, MD
Dr. Francis Long
----------------------------------
Masdon ENT & Facial Plastic Surgery
Corey Cahill, CRNP
Dr. James Masdon
----------------------------------
North Alabama ENT Associates - Huntsville
Dr. Samih Nassif
Dr. John Kostrzewa
----------------------------------
North Alabama ENT Associates - Madison
Dr. John Kostrzewa
----------------------------------
UAB Medicine – The Kirklin Clinic
Dr. Kirk Withrow
----------------------------------
USA Neurosurgery Specialists
Dr. Andrew Romeo
----------------------------------
Valley ENT Associates - Athens
Dr. Paul Papajohn
Dr. James Masdon
----------------------------------
Valley ENT Associates - Madison
Dr. Paul Papajohn
Dr. James Masdon
----------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0

